# Is there a Celtic folklore or mythology story associated with the Hill of Mael in Ireland?

Tags: myth-identification, folklore, irish

Does anyone have any record of a story associated with the trivallate settlement complex on the Hill of Mael in Co. Westmeath, Ireland?

I am looking for earlier Celtic stories under Irish mythology.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mythology and Folklore, could you specify what kind of story you are looking for? Irish mythology, folklore, or tales? Do you search for stories associated with ST. Patrick? Or earlier Celtic stories? Please edit the question to clarify what you are searching for. It will help the answerers to look in the right direction.

Comment: Hello and thanks for that. I am looking for earlier Celtic stories under Irish mythology.